# Issues with Google Places API results

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google Places API to list every location of KFC in the United States. They have more than 4000 outlets in U.S. When I search for "KFC in USA". I get only 100 results. I tried even searching by state but the results are not even close to accuracy.

Is there any other way to search?

Answer (score 0):

i think the default code provided by google search nearby your current location.if you are using the same code from tutortial than try broadning the search area

Answer (score 0):

Just to set correct expectations, Google Places API is not working as a database search. There is no guarantee that all possible items will be returned. Typically, only most prominent results are returned.

Getting all possible results will be in contradiction with restriction set in the Terms of Service paragraph 10.4 c (ii)

> *No creation or augmentation of data sets based on Google’s Content or Services.* You will not use Google’s Content or Services to create or augment your own mapping-related dataset (or that of a third party), including a mapping or navigation dataset, **business listings database**, mailing list, or telemarketing list.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#section_10_4

Answer (score 0):

Google Nearby Search has limitations of 50km radius and 200 results for a single query.  So it will not cover all USA or all 4000 stores without breaking down the search into many smaller areas.

You can buy a list of all KFC locations from AggData.  They create their own scripts to scrape company store locator websites.
https://www.aggdata.com/aggdata/complete-list-kfc-us-locations